# how change type of ArrayList popped from stack from object to linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I'm creating ArrayLists and store them using push() in the Stack. 
however when i'm popping it gives me an error that `Object cannot be converted to List<Integer>`. This is my code:

```
 List<Integer> myl=new ArrayList<Integer>();
 myl=myStack.pop();
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of your stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

```
List<Integer> myl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

can be simplified to:

```
List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

The diamond operator allows to avoid repeating the type information. I also changed it to use a *meaningful* names. Don't use abbreviations that carry no meaning. Use something your readers understand easily.

And then, you simply need a cast:

```
items = (List<Integer>) myStack.pop();
```

Of course that requires that you **really** have a list on top of your stack!

Idealy, your stack **itself** could support generics, so that you could say something like:

```
MyStack<List<Integer>> myStack = new MyStack<>();
```

so you can later simply go

```
items = myStack.pop();
```

without a cast!

You see, when your method signature says `this method returns Object`, then how is the compiler supposed to know that in this case, because you added a list earlier on, the value has a more specific type?!

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification, I was able to proceed however  I have one more question, i was not able to run without the inner type information on the right side of double list like here.  List<List<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<List<>>();